# Insert 0s into 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array `x`:

```
x = [0, -1, 0, 3]
```

and I want `y`:

```
y = [[0, -2, 0, 2],
     [0, -1, 0, 3],
     [0,  0, 0, 4]]
```

where the first row is `x-1`, the second row is `x`, and the third row is `x+1`.  All even column indices are zero.

I'm doing:

```
y=np.vstack(x-1, x, x+1)
y[0][::2] = 0
y[1][::2] = 0
y[2][::2] = 0
```

I was thinking there might be a one-liner to do this instead of 4.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### In two lines

```
>>> x = np.array([0, -1, 0, 3])
>>> y = np.vstack((x-1, x, x+1))
>>> y[:,::2] = 0
>>> y
array([[ 0, -2,  0,  2],
       [ 0, -1,  0,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  4]])
```

### Explanation

```
y[:, ::2]
```

gives the full first dimension. i.e all rows and every other entry form the second dimension, i.e. the columns:

```
array([[-1, -1],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 1,  1]])
```

This is different from:

```
y[:][::2]
```

because this works in two steps. Step one:

```
y[:]
```

gives a view of the whole array:

```
array([[-1, -2, -1,  2],
       [ 0, -1,  0,  3],
       [ 1,  0,  1,  4]])
```

Therefore, step two is doing essentially this:

```
y[::2]
array([[-1, -2, -1,  2],
       [ 1,  0,  1,  4]])
```

It works along the first dimension. i.e. the rows.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but why doesn't `y[:][::2]=0` work?  I tried that initially and assumed it would function the same way as `y[:,::2]=0`.

Comment: @AB `y[:]` is equivalent to `y`, since it indexes the entire contents of the array. `y[:][::2]` is therefore equivalent to `y[::2]`, which is indexing every other *row* rather than every other *column*.

Answer (score 4):

Or alternatively, use [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, -1, 0, 3])
delta = np.array([-1, 0, 1])
y = x + delta[:, None]
y[:, ::2] = 0

print(repr(y))
# array([[ 0, -2,  0,  2],
#        [ 0, -1,  0,  3],
#        [ 0,  0,  0,  4]])
```

- `delta` specifies how much to add/subtract from each row
- Indexing with `None` inserts a new dimension of size 1
- `delta[:, None].shape == (3, 1)` and `x.shape == (4,)`, so the result of `x + delta[:, None]` gets broadcast out to a `(3, 4)` array
- Finally, `y[:, ::2] = 0` fills every other column with zeros.

Answer (score 3):

Using [NumPy's broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for a one-liner -

```
(np.arange(x.size)%2)*(x + np.array([-1,0,1])[:,None])
```

Explanation -

1. `np.arange(x.size)%2)` gives us alternating `0s` and `1s`.
2. Use broadcasting with `x + np.array([-1,0,1])[:,None])` to get the summations in a vectorized manner.
3. Use the alternating `1s` and `0s` created in `step-1` to set or not-set the columns of the summed array in step-2 and thus produce the final output.

Sample run -

```
In [40]: x
Out[40]: array([ 0, -1,  0,  3])

In [41]: (np.arange(x.size)%2)*(x + np.array([-1,0,1])[:,None])
Out[41]: 
array([[ 0, -2,  0,  2],
       [ 0, -1,  0,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

One-liner without `numpy`:

```
x = [0, -1, 0, 3]
y = [ [(x[i] - j if i%2 else 0) for i in range(4)] for j in (1,0,-1)]
```

gives following `y`:

```
[[0, -2, 0, 2], [0, -1, 0, 3], [0,  0, 0, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would have viewed this differently.  You're not adding `1` to `x`, you're adding `[0, 1, 0, 1]`.

```
x = np.array([0, -1, 0, 3])
d = np.resize([0, 1], len(x))
y = np.vstack((x-d, x, x+d))
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner in NumPy:

```
>>> x = np.array([0, -1, 0, 3])
>>> y = np.vstack((x-1, x, x+1)) * np.resize([0, 1], len(x))
>>> y
array([[ 0, -2,  0,  2],
       [ 0, -1,  0,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

a short version : `[[-1],[0],[1]]*(x!=0)+x`.

`[[-1],[0],[1]]*(x!=0)` is

```
     |-1                                    |-1                   | 0 -1 0 -1 |
dot( |0  , [True False True False] ) = dot( |0  ,  [ 1 0 1 0] ) = | 0  0 0  0 |  = z
     |1                                     |1                    | 0  1 0  1 |
```

z + x is : (braodcasting)

```
| 0 -1 0 -1 |   | 0 -1 0 3 |    | 0 -2 0 2 |
| 0  0 0  0 | + | 0 -1 0 3 |  = | 0 -1 0 3 |
| 0  1 0  1 |   | 0 -1 0 3 |    | 0  0 0 4 |
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)